# How to get and terminate specific processes from a remote server without the IDs? C#

Tags: c#, .net, process, wmi, remote-server

(**TLDR;** There are a lot of posts that deal with remote processes, but I need to get a very specific set of processes based on a particular path/environment name and I don’t have any of the IDs handy.)

I have been asked to make a small application that displays all the processes running from a particular service in a particular environment on a particular server. A user will select the service they want to restart, and the application will restart it behind the scenes and do the necessary cleanup.
The structure of the services is as follows:

**Server --> Environments --> Services --> Process(es)**

And the service’s processes have a hierarchy as follows:

**wrapper.exe --> java.exe --> tss.exe**

When restarting a given service, there are sometimes tss.exe’s left over, which causes the startup process to fail. My application will need to be able to locate and terminate these orphaned processes.
The only information I have about these processes is the name, and the full filepath, which looks like this:

**\\serverName\T$\Accounts\environmentName\bnk.run\t24bin\eb_interface**

I don’t have any of the process IDs, and there are usually multiple tss.exe’s and wrapper.exe’s running on one server. I want to be able to locate only those associated with the service in question. The only way that I can think of to figure this out is to use the environment name in the filepath, get the ID of the parent wrapper.exe process, and get the children from there.

I have run into multiple problems so far…

The Process class does not allow me to terminate a remote process, and I also can’t use the path to figure out which tss.exe’s belong to what service.
Using the WMI Win32_Process class has given me a bunch of errors:

“Function evaluation disabled because a previous function evaluation timed out. You must continue execution to re-enable function evaluation.”

Through debugging I have found that it is throwing a `System.TypeInitializationException` on all the `ManagementPath` properties (internally it throws a `System.Threading.ThreadAbortException`).
And the process `ManagementObject` gives the same error for classpath, properties, and qualifiers.
The test method I was running gets all the processes and displays their names in a textbox on a Windows form:

```
        ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope(@"\\serverName\root\cimv2");

        var query = new SelectQuery("select * from Win32_Process where name = 'tss.exe'");

        using (var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query))
        {
            foreach (ManagementObject process in searcher.Get()) 
            {
                processDisplay.Text += " " + process.GetPropertyValue("Name");
            }
        }
```

The code does display the process names correctly for the whole server, but I still get the above errors, and don’t understand if it is working, or if it will cause me problems later on when I try to get more information from my process objects.

My questions are then:

Why am I getting these errors? If they are fixed, can I do what I want to do using the WMI process management?

Or if not, what other way could I go about this?